# Python generic protocol: TypeVar is "Unknown" (Pylance) or "Any" (Mypy)

Tags: python, mypy, pylance

For a generic class or protocol, why is the result of `f()` stored in `fout` here "Unknown" (Pylance v2023.4.30) or "Any" (mypy v1.2.0) rather than "T@MyProto"? This is mostly academic, as the goal for `fout` to be a valid input to `g()`, which Unknown/Any obviously is.

```
import typing as t

T = t.TypeVar("T")


class MyProto(t.Protocol[T]):
    def f(self) -> T:
        ...

    def g(self, fout: T) -> t.Any:
        ...


tup: t.Tuple[MyProto, ...] = tuple()

for item in tup:
    fout = item.f()
    reveal_type(fout)
    # Type of "fout" is "Unknown" (Pylance)
    item.g(fout)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of answer you're looking for with this question. You haven't given the type checker any constraints, so what else would you expect?

Comment: If your goal is to silence lints due to the lack of constraints, you could try using `MyProto[t.Any]` instead of leaving the generic umparametrized

Comment: @Brian61354270 was expecting T@MyProto, which is the result of reveal_type(fout) inside of g(). The only goal here is to better understand the behavior of checkers w/r/t generics.

Comment: `T@MyProto` (pylance notation) exists exclusively within `MyProto` body - there is no such thing like "type of attribute x of object y of type Y" unless it can be described as some static type which does not depend on y. And `T` is bound to some instance (`item`), not to the class.

Comment: because `MyProto` is implicitly `MyProto[Any]` if you don't parameterize it